# gedit : plugin "imitation" doesn't work after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, gedit, plugins

Unfortunately, I can't use the `gedit` plugins called `imitation` and "regex search and replace" after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.

Anyone could help me, please?

I already ran:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
sudo chown peter /home/peter/.config/gedit
```

Comment: Are there error messages?

Comment: indeed:

the plugin 'imitation' could not be loaded
An error occurred: Plugin loader 'python" was not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to update your version of the imitation plugin for 14.04 / gedit3.10.

1. Download the plugin source tarball from [here](http://codetree.com.au/static/content/imitation/releases/imitation-1.3.tar.gz) (Imitation 1.3 for gedit 3.8+).
2. Extract `imitation-1.3.tar.gz` (e.g. using Nautilus)

   You should get the following tree structure:

   ```
   .
   ├── COPYING
   ├── imitation
   │   ├── config.py
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── iter.py
   │   └── tab.py
   ├── imitation.plugin
   └── org.gnome.gedit.plugins.imitation.gschema.xml
   ```
3. Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
4. Run the following commands:

   `cd ~/Downloads/imitation-1.3` (or where you extracted the `.tar.gz` file)

   ```
   sudo cp org.gnome.gedit.plugins.imitation.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas

   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas

   sudo cp -R imitation.plugin imitation/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins
   ```

   Or for a 32bits system:

   ```
   sudo cp -R imitation.plugin imitation/ /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins
   ```
5. Activate Imitation in gedit's preferences

Comment: thanks for your response but after running the last command I get the following response in my terminal 
"cp: impossible d'évaluer «imitation/»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
"  [impossible to evaluate «imitation/»: no file or folder of this type]

:-( ; is there something I can do about that?

Comment: under `~/Downloads/imitation-1.3` you should have a `imitation.plugin` file and a directory named `imitation/`. Can you see both? They are normally there is you extracted the whole tar.gz

Comment: I've updated my answer with the content of the archive, could you check that you have the same tree structure (with an imitation folder) please?

Comment: i changed the file structure and ran than the other commands and IT'S WORKING.

thank you very much. i'm learning html5 and css3 : this will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for this. Imitation's install instructions are very lacking. The only thing I did differently was change the last command where you move the plugin to gedit. I changed the copy destination to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`